# Sequelizejs - Create, but specify "returning" option to return only specific fields

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

My database is Postgres, and am connecting to it via Nodejs and Sequelizejs.

I want to `INSERT` a new row using Sequelizejs, but on inserting I only want it to `RETURN` specific columns in the table, not *all* the columns in the table. Here is an example:

```
let response = await db.fruits.create({
    name: 'apple',
    color: 'red'
},
{
    returning: ['name', 'color']
});
```

This will add a new record to the `fruits` table. This table has 5 columns, but I only want it to return 2 columns (the `name` and `color` columns). The above example does not work - it will insert the new record, but it will return all 5 columns in the table, when I only want it to return the 2 columns I specified.

According to the docs here:

[https://sequelize.org/master/class/lib/model.js~Model.html#static-method-create](https://sequelize.org/master/class/lib/model.js%7EModel.html#static-method-create)

We should be able to specify the returning columns. I can't seem to figure out how.

Comment: See the following bug report:  https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/11904

Comment: Try `bulkCreate`, it returns the columns specified in the first parameter plus the ones in the `returning`. At least it doesn't ignore the `returning` options

Comment: encountering the same issue